# SQL Server stored procedure locking issue?

Tags: sql, sql-server, stored-procedures

I created this pretty basic stored procedure, that gets called by our cms when a user creates a specific type of item. However, it looks like there are times when we get two rows for each cms item created with the same data, but an off-by-one `SourceID`. I don't do much SQL work, so this might be something basic - but do I need to explicitly lock the table somehow in the stored procedure to keep this from happening?

Here is the stored procedure code:

```
BEGIN
    SET @newid = (SELECT MAX(SourceID)+1 from [dbo].[sourcecode])

    IF NOT EXISTS(SELECT SourceId from [dbo].[sourcecode] where SourceId = @newid)
        INSERT INTO [dbo].[sourcecode]
            (
                SourceID,
                Description,
                RunCounts,
                ShowOnReport,
                SourceParentID,
                ApprovedSource,
                Created
            )
        VALUES
            (
                @newid,
                @Desc,
                1,
                @ShowOnReport,
                1,
                1,
                GetDate()
            )

    RETURN @newid
END
```

and here is an example of the duplicated data (less a couple of irrelevant columns):

```
SourceId    Description Created
676         some text   2012-10-17 09:42:36.553
677         some text   2012-10-17 09:43:01.380
```

Comment: I doubt this is a result of the stored procedure. Look into your codebase - you are probably calling the stored procedure twice in quick succession. The times on the two rows are almost 30 seconds apart - are you sure this is not someone submitting the same data twice?

Comment: Note: Why not use an `IDENTITY` column instead of faffing around with incrementing `@newid`?

Comment: that's just the way the table was set up when i got it. our dba used to insert these manually every time someone wanted a new one, i just set up our cms to automatically do that process.

Comment: Go with using the IDENTITY column as @Oded suggests. Your dba was making too much work for him or herself and now you by the looks of it.

Comment: THat `max(id)+1` approach is **not safe** under load... you could end up with duplicate entries with the same `id` ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am sure this has nothing to do with SP. As Oded mentioned, this could be the result of your code.
I don't see anything in the stored procedure which is capable of generating duplicates.
Also, I wouldn't use MAX(SourceId) + 1. Why don't you use "Auto Increment" if you want a new Source Id all the time anyways?

Comment: i'll look into doing it this way instead.

Answer (score 0):

You can use locking when using stored procedures. On the ones I use I usually use `WITH (ROWLOCK)`. Locking is used to ensure data integrity. I think a simple Google should bring up lots of information about why you should be using locking.

But as other commentators had said, see if there isn't anything in your code as well. Is there something that is calling the same method twice? Are there 'events' referencing the method that is doing the updating?

Comment: i guess it's possible the cms is calling the code where i call the sproc twice, but this is all done via a config file where you hook up events and the cms uses reflection to call your code. i can't really help if the cms we're using is doing that - i was hoping for a simple sql modification where the sproc above just wouldn't do anything if the cms happened to run my create code twice...

Comment: The problem then is what logic do you add to the SProc to say 'have I been called twice, when I shouldn't have?'. What is your CMS written in? I've encountered problems like this when I was using ASP.NET. In that case I'd got methods in PageRender and PageLoad and I'd got myself in a muddle with them.  http://rrajusingh.files.wordpress.com/2010/09/page_lifecycle3.png

Answer (score 0):

As it has been said in the comments, I think your issue is more in the code layer; none of the  data seems to be violating any constraints. You may want to do a check to see if the same user has submitted the same data "recently" before performing the insert.

Answer (score -2):

The description is probably duplicated because you are calling the same function twice, by clicking the button twice, or whatever.

You should use an [`IDENTITY`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186775.aspx) on your SourceID column and use the `Scope_Identity()` function

If you don't want to do that for some reason, then you should wrap the above code in a transaction with the isolation level set to `Serializable`

```
SET TRANSACTION ISOLATION LEVEL SERIALIZABLE
BEGIN TRAN
    SET @newid = ....


COMMIT
```

Comment: That is not answering the question. OP wants to know why the `description` is duplicated...

Comment: @Oded It's exactly the same as Paul's answer. Why not downvote him too?

Comment: You assume you have been downvoted by me (at the moment, there are _two_ downvotes on this answer, so more than one person thinks this is not a good answer). Also, you will find as you gain reputation - people with high reputation are held to a higher standard than those with low reputation.

Comment: @Oded then I should assume that all your answers are absolutely perfect in content, grammar and formatting?

Comment: You are reading what you want to read into my words. The simple fact is - this doesn't answer the issue the OP is having. It is a tangent to the question. That's probably why you have gotten downvotes. The simple option is to delete this irrelevant answer and regain the lost reputation.

Comment: As for you dig about the answer from Paul - he seems to have the good sense to delete his answer as it is indeed not relevant.

Comment: @Oded You assume I care about 4 points! I wasn't digging at Paul, I was digging at your selective negativity.

Comment: Then what _do_ you care about? Why are you asking about what I do or do not do?